# Match Custom formula using regular Expressions

Tags: regex, formula

I am trying match a formula using regular expressions.

1. The formula should strictly contain these three letters only(L,W,H).
2. Should allow only product operation i.e `(L*W*H, L*W, L*H etc).`
3. Also instead of adding squared values, It should allow something
   like this`(L*L*L*W*W*H*H)`
4. Also it should not allow  the asterisk symbol at the end.

I tried myself and came up with this

```
^([L|W|H]\*{0,1})?(([L|W|H]\*{0,1}){0,9})?([L|W|H]{0,1})$
```

But this allows adding letters continuously something like `"LLL*WW*HHH**"`. Please help me out guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you want this:

`^[LWH](\*[LWH])*$`

Explanation:

- `^` the start of string
- `[LWH]` one of L,W,H
- `(\*[LWH])*` (a literal `*` followed by one of L,W,H) any number of times
- `$` the end of string